# "More than one operator>> matches these operands. Operand types are: std::ifstream&>>size_t"

Tags: c++, serialization, operator-overloading, iostream

I have a "Serializable" interface class, that has

```
struct Serializable {
    virtual void write(std::ostream& os = std::cout) const = 0;
    virtual void read(std::istream& is = std::cin) = 0;
};
```

so that the derivates' implementations can have a simple form like:

```
void write(std::ostream& os = std::cout) {os<<*this}
void read(std::istream& is = std::cin) {is>>*this}
```

that work on all kinds of ostream objects by having the operators in question overloaded by the appropriate iostream derivates like:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Vec2D& rhs_vec) {...}
```

and:

```
//I.
std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& ifs, Vec2D& rhs_vec) {...}
//intellisense thinks the above line is an overload for 
//std::ifstream&>>size_t
```

or:

```
std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream ifs, Document<Shape>& document) 
{
    size_t siz;
    ifs >> siz; //II. the >> is red curly underlined by intellisense
    document.setCapacity(siz);
    ...
}
```

The line marked by the comment II. is where I get the intellisense error I wrote in the title, mentioning the definition marked by comment I. among 2 other similar definitions as possible overloads for std::ifstream&>>size_t.

How on earth is it (or are these) overloards for std::ifstream&>>size_t, when they are clearly not?

Is there something fundamentally wrong with my design, or is it just some intellisense madness?

Comment: "I get the intellisense error" Does it compile though?

Comment: The reason is that you are overloading `operator>>()` to work with `std::ifstream` rather than `std::istream`.   When doing `ifs >> size`, a reference to `std::ifstream` means that your overloaded `operator>>()` is also a candidate.  That is confusing intellisense.   Even if  your code compiles, you may find your `read()` functions don't call the `operator>>()` in every case where you expect it to).  To eliminate the problem (actually range of problems) overload your `operator>>()` to work with `std::istream` rather than `std::ifstream`.

Comment: my goal was to write differently to console and file, so if I call operator << with ofstream and something, why can the compiler not see that ofstream is a more specialized class than ostream and call the appropriate overload?